# How to stop a runner spawned from a method in Android?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have a method test() inside my onPrepared(Mediaplayer mp) method. The test() spawns a runnable and does the following :

```
public void test() {
    Runnable playerValues = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out
                    .println("Player.testPlaying() --> Get Duration : "
                            + vv.getDuration());
            System.out
                    .println("Player.testPlaying() --> Total Bytes Read : "
                            + Download.totalBytesRead);
            System.out
                    .println("Player.testPlaying() --> Current Position : "
                            + vv.getCurrentPosition());
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(playerValues, 1000);
}
```

At OnCompletion method of the player i want to stop this Runnable. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handler.[removeCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)(playerValues).  (I think you'll want to declare playerValues as a field for that to work, because otherwise handler won't have the scope to see it.)

Comment: how to declare it as field? i dint get that.

Comment: Presumably you're declaring handler somewhere like `private final Handler handler = new Handler()` - in the same place you'll want to also declare `private final Runnable playerValues = new Runnable()` in the same place.  (Or public or protected or whatever.)

Comment: you mean i should take it out of the function and define it outside??